# Front Door is not working with access_token from /services/oauth2/token with grant_type=password

Tags: frontdoor.jsp

I am trying to use Front Door:

https://instance.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=session_ID

I have created a Connected App with `full` and `web` scopes.

I have sent this request via Postman:

```
curl --location 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: BrowserId=v-zKoAX_Ee6oNUeUP12vNQ; CookieConsentPolicy=0:0; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:0' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=ERASED' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=ERASED' \
--data-urlencode 'username=ERASED' \
--data-urlencode 'password=ERASED'
```

I have received instance_url and access_token in the response.

I have configured an url:

{{instance_url}}/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid={{access_token}}

This leads me to a login page.

The same access_token works perfectly with the REST API of salesforce, for example, I can retrieve a list of users:

```
curl --location '{{instance_url}}/services/data/v57.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20Email%20FROM%20user' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ERASED' \
--header 'Cookie: BrowserId=v-zKoAX_Ee6oNUeUP12vNQ; CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1' \
--data ''
```

Front Door is also working fine with the session_id from Apex: `UserInfo.getSessionId()` and also with SOAP. But it doesn't work with the access_token from Postman. What am I missing?

Probably, [this is](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) a problem (have found it in the answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369243/using-access-token-from-oauth-2-0-username-password-flow-to-access-data-export-p))?

> This flow [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow] doesn’t support scopes or refresh tokens. Experience Cloud sites don’t support the OAuth 2.0 username-password flow.

Is there any way to use access_token from `grant_type=password` in the Front Door?

Comment: `full` is a superset, you don't need `web` if you request `full`. What license is attached to the User whose credentials (username/password) you use to obtain the access token

Comment: Salesforce User license and standard system administrator profile.

Comment: Can confirm that it fails - tried on my dev ed org and a regular sandbox. Also tried a few other variations of flows/scopes, they all failed. Grabbing the session ID from a regular UI session does work with frontdoor, so must be the connected app. Open a support case.

Comment: ..other variations of flows included client creds. Did not try authorization code or hybrid/user agent flows. The latter two might work since there's explicit consent to access.

Comment: We have tried soap (username/password), it doesn't require explicit consent, but works fine. So why rest cannot work the same? :(

Comment: Have created a case for sf support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a response from SF Support. Long story short: we cannot use session_id from REST API username/password flow with the frontdoor.

> The username-password flow generates access tokens as Salesforce Session IDs that can’t be introspected. Because the access tokens are temporary, connected apps that are using this flow aren’t displayed on the Connected Apps OAuth Usage page, even if they have an active session.

According to this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193348&language=en_US&type=1):

> Not all session types are supported with frontdoor.jsp

So, you can use the other OAuth flows that are supported like Web Server flow.